# Why Angular-cron-jobs generates the same cron expression for "Every Minute", "Every Hour at 0 past hour","Every Day at 0:0" etc

Tags: angularjs, cron, cronexpression

As the question has suggested, if you play around with DEMO BASIC at http://jacobscarter.github.io/angular-cron-jobs/#/ you will see that "Every Minute", "Every Hour at 0 past hour","Every Day at 0:0","Every Week on  at 0:0" all generates the same expression: *****

The same problematic thing happens when you select Every Year, no matter what month you select, the cron expression may be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a problem with the demo using an older version on angular-cron-jobs.  This issue was fixed a few versions ago.  I updated the Demo.  Thanks for pointing this out.

http://jacobscarter.github.io/angular-cron-jobs/#/

Comment: This link is no more valid!